# Text code decoding

Tags: encoding, mobile

I am an English/Spanish Spanish/English translator. I have been given a job where I have to translate Spanish text messages sent from cell phones. Some of them are in code. I assume each set of figures represents a letter. Is there any website where I can find information on how to decipher the code?

For instance, the first message says:

‘0x69 ox61 0x6e 0x70 0x72 0x2e 0x6e 0x65 0x74 0x2f 0x3f 0x64 0x34 0x39 0x31 0x66 0x30 0x37 0x38 0x35 0x35 0x32 0x39 0x62 0x36 0x31 0x31 0x00

Thank you for any help you provide.

Diana

Comment: WTF is close-voting? This is a totally valid and justified question. Somebody has to tell me how hex isn't programming related nowadays...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [Hex-to-ASCII decoder](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) that can take your input format without modification (paste into the "0x... notation" box and press Convert).

BTW, in order to help you understand: those "sets of figures" each represent a byte, written as a hexadecimal number (base 16). The 0x prefix is how hexadecimal numbers are written in the C programming language (and many others). So now you have a series of bytes. Those then need to be interpreted as characters, through a set of rules known as "character encoding". This has to happen everywhere computers display text. Unfortunately, there are many different incompatible character encodings. Most of them agree on how to interpret the first 128 values a byte can take (the US-ASCII encoding). But if you deal with Spanish text, you'll quickly encounter characters that are not representable in ASCII. Then it becomes important to choose the correct encoding; I doubt there is an online tool for converting Hex notation that allows you to choose the encoding.

Comment: Hello Mr. Borgwardt. I don't know how to post a thank you to everyone who answered my question. I wish to thank you, and I respectfully request that you forward my thanks to all the other persons who replied to my question. Your Hex-to-ASCII decoder has been helpful. Some of the text is corrupted but I have been able to understand some of what the message says.

Comment: @Diana: You're welcome. Comments like this are visible to everyone; You can post comments to every answer separately, but the custom is to write messages to everyone as a comment to the question itself.

Comment: Ach, es gehet mir sehr gut, danke!  
I find this quite interesting. At first I was just going to place a footnote in my translation saying that I was unable to ascertain what the text was since I don't know HEX or ASCII but your conversion link has allowed me to see portions of the text that I am able to translate.

Comment: (I was provided with the actual text of only one person. The other person's messages are in HEX.) Usually when people text message in Spanish here in Puerto Rico they skip the accents and special letters because most of the cell phones and computers used here are manufactured with English characters and readers understand.

Answer (score 3):

It's a hex-encoded URL, according to [this translator](http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/):

ianpr.net/?d491f0785529b611

Comment: Note that you should remove these "0x" before trying that converter.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like Ascii code to me.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII - look at the hex coding. For example 0x69 would be an i.

Comment: Thank you for your reply to my question. I am using the HEX to ASCII converter that Mr. Borgwardt provided and I am now able to see the text and translate.

Answer (score 1):

Something like 'ianpr.net/?d491f0785529b611\x00'

:)

Decoding in Python:

```
a = "0x69 0x61 0x6e 0x70 0x72 0x2e 0x6e 0x65 0x74 0x2f 0x3f 0x64 0x34 0x39 0x31 0x66 0x30 0x37 0x38 0x35 0x35 0x32 0x39 0x62 0x36 0x31 0x31 0x00"
b = ""
for  i in a.split():
  b = b + chr(int(i[2]+i[3], 16))
print b
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply to my question. I am using the HEX to ASCII converter that Mr. Borgwardt provided and I am now able to see the text and translate.

Answer (score 1):

Careful, if it is text messages then it is [GSM-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38), not ascii

Comment: Thank you for your caveat fravelgue. I entered the string of numbers/letters into the converter that Mr. Borgwardt provided and I got intelligible text. For example: 0x4e 0x69 0x74 0x65 0x20 0x6e 0x69 0x74 0x65 0x20 0x61 0x6e ox64 0x20 0x73 0x77 0x65 0x65 0x74 0x20 0x64 0x72 0x65 0x61 0x6d 0x73 0x2e 0x20 0x20 0x4c 0x69 0x6b 0x65 0x20 0x49 0x20 0x73 0x61 0x69 0x64 0x20 0x49 0x20 0x77 0x69 0x6c 0x6c 0x20 0x6c 0x76 0x20 0x7 rendered Nite nite and sweet dreams. Like I said I will love... But for accuracy's sake, is this really GSM-7?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like hex values, and if it's just ASCII text in hex, you can use a converter to see what the message is.

http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply to my question. I am using the HEX to ASCII converter that Mr. Borgwardt provided and I am now able to see the text and translate.